Pkcs#11 with Luna Cloud HSM: private key listed with cmu list is not found in Java KeyStore
Connecting to Luna Cloud HSM I am able to add a RSA private key to the HSM (either by cmu importkey or by cmu gen) and the command-line tool cmu list displays this key from the server.
I am connecting to the HSM using Pkcs#11 with minimal configuration file
name=LunaHsm
description=SunPKCS11 accessing LunaHsm
library=libCryptoki2.so
showInfo=true
slot=3

But I cannot find the private key as I was expecting. I enabled logging for java.security.debug=sunpkcs11 (log bellow) and the Java code is correctly initializing the PKCS#11 library, listing the correct information for the provider SunPKCS11-LunaHsm, it finds the correct slot but it only finds the secret keys present on this slot, without the private key I was expecting to find. I'm using OpenJdk 11.0.18
SunPKCS11 loading lunahsm-pkcs11.cfg
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library libCryptoki2.so
Information for provider SunPKCS11-LunaHsm
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: 2.20
  manufacturerID: SafeNet                         
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: Chrystoki                       
  libraryVersion: 10.07
All slots: 0, 1, 2, 3
Slots with tokens: 3
Slot info for slot 3:
  slotDescription: Net Token Slot                                                  
  manufacturerID: SafeNet                         
  flags: CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT | CKF_REMOVABLE_DEVICE | CKF_HW_SLOT
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
Token info for token in slot 3:
  label: my_partition          
  manufacturerID: SafeNet                         
  model: Cryptovisor7    
  serialNumber: 123123   
  flags: CKF_RNG | CKF_LOGIN_REQUIRED | CKF_USER_PIN_INITIALIZED | CKF_RESTORE_KEY_NOT_NEEDED | CKF_TOKEN_INITIALIZED
  ulMaxSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulSessionCount: 1
  ulMaxRwSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulRwSessionCount: 1
  ulMaxPinLen: 255
  ulMinPinLen: 7
  ulTotalPublicMemory: 159744
  ulFreePublicMemory: 156528
  ulTotalPrivateMemory: 159744
  ulFreePrivateMemory: 156528
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 7.03
  utcTime: 20241008132333  
<list of Mechanisms>
sunpkcs11: login succeeded

If I use the Luna JSP LunaProvider.jar then I can find also the private keys:
Security.addProvider(new LunaProvider());
myStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Luna");
ByteArrayInputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                ("slot:" + slot + "\ncaching:false" + "\ndefertokenization:true").getBytes());
myStore.load(is1, passwd.toCharArray());

But I want to only use the Pkcs#11 API:
Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
provider = provider.configure("path/to/config/file");
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", provider);
ks.load(is1,passwd.toCharArray());

Any suggestion?

Is the matching cert also there? SunPKCS11 provider only exposes privatekeys that have a matching cert. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868447/sunpkcs11-usage-against-hsm-without-cko-certificate and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78895148/can-i-provide-the-public-key-to-jarsigner-on-the-command-line and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.html#GUID-F068390B-EB41-48A0-A713-B4CBCC72285D

I just tested SunPKCS11 with Luna HSM. Here's how it worked for me.
sampaul@jaguarkick:~$ openssl rand -hex 8
df019547a558d541

sampaul@jaguarkick:~$ cmu gen -sign 1 -verify 1 -encrypt 1 -decrypt 1 -publicexponent 65537 -modulusBits 2048 -keytype rsa -id=df019547a558d541

sampaul@jaguarkick:~$ cmu self -id=df019547a558d541 -label=signing_key

sampaul@jaguarkick:~$ java SunPKCS11Test.java config.cfg userpinco signing_key

SunPKCS11 Configuration:
sampaul@jaguarkick:~$ cat config.cfg
name = Luna
library = /usr/safenet/lunaclient/lib/libcklog2.so
slot = 0

SunPKCS11Test.java:
import java.security.*;
import java.security.KeyStore.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class SunPKCS11Test {
        private static String fileName = null;
        private static String slotPin = null;
        private static String keyAlias = null;
        private static final String RAW_DATA = "Earth is the third planet of our Solar System.";
        private static byte[] signature = null;
        private static final String PROVIDER = "SunPKCS11-Luna";
        private static KeyStore keyStore = null;
        private static PrivateKeyEntry prKe = null;

        private static void addSunPKCS11() {
                Provider prod = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
                prod = prod.configure(fileName);
                Security.insertProviderAt(prod, 5);
        }

        private static void loadKeyStore() throws Exception {
                keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", PROVIDER);
                keyStore.load(null, slotPin.toCharArray());
        }

        private static void signData() throws Exception {
                Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("sha256WithRSA", PROVIDER);
                sign.initSign(prKe.getPrivateKey());
                sign.update(RAW_DATA.getBytes());
                signature = sign.sign();
        }

        private static void loadSigningKeys() throws Exception {
                prKe = (PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(keyAlias, new PasswordProtection("abcd".toCharArray()));
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                fileName = args[0];
                slotPin = args[1];
                keyAlias = args[2];
                addSunPKCS11();
                loadKeyStore();
                loadSigningKeys();
                signData();
        }
}

Hope this helps!

Using this native library fails for me during provider configure(), using OpenJdk 11:
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library /usr/safenet/lunaclient/lib/libcklog2.so
sunpkcs11: Multi-threaded initialization failed: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.(SunPKCS11.java:382)

What solves my problem is creating the private key + public key + certificate in the HSM with the commands you listed. Not sure what the problem was with the way I was doing this before, ie. creating a private key + certificate locally then importing these in the HSM

I am using the libCryptoki2.so native library from the minimal client I installed for my service

libcklog2.so is used for debugging a pkcs11 application. If it's not enabled then CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED is returned. The actual pkcs11 library is libCryptoki2.so.


For java based applications, best option is to generate keys directly using keytool instead of using cmu. keytool is a java utility and it will always generate keys in a format that sunpkcs11 understands.


If you're generating keys using CMU then you need to assign an ID (CKA_ID) to your keypair and certificate. No labels for private and public key, set a label to certificate.



I think your Java code using SunPKCS11 cannot find your keys because the configuration file you're using for the SunPKCS11 provider is missing key attributes. SunPKCS11 relies on the key attributes specified in the configuration file to locate keys. For example :-
name = Luna
library = /usr/safenet/lunaclient/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so
slot = 0
showInfo=false

attributes(*, CKO_PRIVATE_KEY, *) = {
    CKA_SIGN = true
    CKA_TOKEN = true
}

attributes(*, CKO_PUBLIC_KEY, *) = {
    CKA_VERIFY = true
}

attributes(*, CKO_SECRET_KEY, *) = {
    CKA_ENCRYPT = true
    CKA_DECRYPT = true
    CKA_WRAP = true
    CKA_UNWRAP = true
    CKA_TOKEN = true
}


That's used when SunPKCS11 CREATES objects not when it looks for them

Sorry, my bad. Forgot about this.. You're right about sunpkcs11 configuration. Thank you.
